# Is there a way to control the order the arguments are evaluated in Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Let's take the example below. The parser contains two arguments --inputfile and verbosity. The Set_verbosity_level() function is used to controls the value of a module-level/global variable (in my real life a package-level variable) to 0-4. The CheckFile() function performs tests inside input file (in the real life depending on type). 
I would like to print messages in CheckFile() depending on verbosity. The problem is that argparse calls CheckFile() before Set_verbosity_level() so the verbosity level is always 0/default in CheckFile...

So my question is whether there is any solution to force argparse to evaluate some arguments before others...

```
    import argparse

    VERBOSITY = 0


    def Set_verbosity_level():
        """Set the verbosity level.
        """

        def type_func(value):
            a_value = int(value)
            globals()['VERBOSITY'] = value
            print("Verbosity inside Set_verbosity_level(): " + str(globals()['VERBOSITY']))
            return value

        return type_func


    class CheckFile(argparse.FileType):
        """
        Check whatever in the file
        """

        def __init__(self, mode='r', **kwargs):
            super(CheckFile, self).__init__(mode, **kwargs)

        def __call__(self, string):
            # Do whatever processing/checking/transformation
            # e.g print some message according to verbosity
            print("Verbosity inside  CheckFile(): " + str(globals()['VERBOSITY']))
            return super(CheckFile, self).__call__(string)


    def make_parser():
        """The main argument parser."""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)

        parser.add_argument("-V",
                            "--verbosity",
                            default=0,
                            type=Set_verbosity_level(),
                            help="Increase output verbosity.",
                            required=False)

        parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputfile',
                            help="Input file",
                            type=CheckFile(mode='r'),
                            required=True)

        return parser


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        myparser = make_parser()
        args = myparser.parse_args()
        print("Verbosity in Main: " + str(VERBOSITY))
```

Calling this script gives:

```
$python test.py -i test.bed -V 2
Verbosity inside  CheckFile(): 0
Verbosity inside Set_verbosity_level(): 2
Verbosity in Main: 2
```

Comment: It parses the inputs in the order that your user provides, and we can't readily change that parsing routine.  I think it makes more sense to `CheckFile` after parsing, when you know the verbosity regardless of input order.  It's better form, in PY3, to open files in a `with` context, which you cannot do with the `argparse.FileType`.  Setting a global `VERBOSITY` from within a `type` function is novel, and not, in my opinion, good Python style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can force an argparse variable to be read first, but you can use pythons built in command line parser in your main function:

```
import sys

# Your classes here #

if __name__ == '__main__':
    verbosity = 0
    for i, sysarg in enumerate(sys.argv):
        if str(sysarg).strip().lower().replace('-','') in ['v', 'verbose']:
            try:
                verbosity = sys.argv[i + 1]
            except IndexError:
                print("No verbosity level specified")
    # more code
```

Its not very elegant and it's not argparse, but it's one way to ensure you get the verbosity first.

You could also update your `CheckFile` class to include a verbosity checking function:

```
class CheckFile(argparse.FileType):
    """
    Check whatever in the file
    """

    def __init__(self, mode='r', **kwargs):
        super(CheckFile, self).__init__(mode, **kwargs)

    def _check_verbosity(self):
        verbosity = 0
        for i, sysarg in enumerate(sys.argv):
            if str(sysarg).strip().lower().replace('-','') in ['v', 'verbose']:
                try:
                verbosity = sys.argv[i + 1]
            except IndexError:
                print("No verbosity level specified")

        return verbosity

    def __call__(self, string):
        # Do whatever processing/checking/transformation
        # e.g print some message according to verbosity
        print("Verbosity inside  CheckFile(): {}".format(self._check_verbosity()))
        return super(CheckFile, self).__call__(string)
```

Again, I know it's not really an answer to your argparse question, but it is a solution for your problem

Comment: I think the second solution should do the trick. Thanks a lot Richard for helping.

Answer (score 2):

`argparse` processes the command-line arguments in the order that they are listed, so if you simply swap the order of the given options, it would output in the verbosity you want:

```
python test.py -V 2 -i test.bed
```

This outputs:

```
Verbosity inside Set_verbosity_level(): 2
Verbosity inside  CheckFile(): 2
```

There's no way otherwise to tell `argparse` to process the command-line arguments in a different order than how they're listed.

Comment: I guess this should be the selected answer to the question 'Is there a way to control the order the arguments are evaluated in Python argparse'. I will choose Richard's answer that goes beyond and proposes a solution to my specific limitation. Best